# SWT - Table Row - Changing font color

Tags: swt, tableviewer

Is it possible to change the font color for a row based on a value in one of the columns?

My table has a column that displays a status.  The value of the column is going to either be Failed or Success.

If it is Success I would like for that rows font be green.  If the status equals Failed, I want that rows font be red.

Is this possible, if so where would I put the logic.

**EDIT**

Here is my Table Viewer code, I am not going to show all the columns, just a couple

```
private void createColumns() {

  String[] titles = { "ItemId", "RevId", "PRL", "Dataset Name", "Printer/Profile" , "Success/Fail" };
  int[] bounds = { 100, 75, 75, 150, 200, 100 };

  TableViewerColumn col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[0], bounds[0], 0);
  col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
     public String getText(Object element) {
        if(element instanceof AplotResultsDataModel.ResultsData) {
           return ((AplotResultsDataModel.ResultsData)element).getItemId();
        }          
        return super.getText(element); 
     }
  }); 

  col = createTableViewerColumn(titles[1], bounds[1], 1);
  col.setLabelProvider(new ColumnLabelProvider() {
     public String getText(Object element) {
        if(element instanceof AplotResultsDataModel.ResultsData) {
           return ((AplotResultsDataModel.ResultsData)element).getRevId();
        }          
        return super.getText(element); 
     }
  });    --ETC
```

Comment: Short answer - it is possible. Detailed answer depends on whether you use SWT table or JFace table viewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check element state and return the color that you want to use

```
Viewer implementation        
    ColumnLabelProvider
        public Color getForeground(Object element)
```

For Table use

```
TableItem
         setForeground(Color color) 
         setForeground(int index, Color color)
```

As  you are using `ColumnLabelProvider` for each column, you need to override getForeground(Object element) for each column. Another way, do not add `ColumnLabelProvider` for each column.

Set `LabelProvider` at `TableViewer` level.

`TableViewer.setLabelProvider(ColumnLabelProvider labelProvider)`. As you don't have label provider set at column level, tableviewer get its display text, image, font, background, foreground, etc. for each cell from the label provider set at `TableViewer` level.

Comment: sambi - Do I have to change it in the Viewer implementation and the TableItem or are you saying one or the other?  I am also using a table viewer.  Would I have to check and change the color in each column?  I am going to paste my column code above.  If you would please show me where and how to implement the logic

Comment: You see that I am using ColumnLabelProvider.  The only reason I am using that is because that was the first example I came across for setting up my table viewer.  If you believe that there is a better way to do set up the columns, please let me know.  I am very new to this and still trying to learn as much as possible about it.  can you give me a example of how to implement either method you suggested above?

Comment: I have figured it out - Thanks